# What is the best way to preserve a LEGO model after it has been built?

Tags: building, preservation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I store LEGO bricks as long as possible?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/172/how-can-i-store-lego-bricks-as-long-as-possible)
>   [How do you store your built models for long term display?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/949/how-do-you-store-your-built-models-for-long-term-display)

I want to preserve my sons LEGO ships after they are built. Is there anything out there to apply as a coating after he is done building it?

Comment: It's not necessary, nor is it a particular good idea to apply coating to your LEGO bricks.

Comment: If you want to consider a permanent construction, take a look at: [What glue should I use for permanent LEGO construction?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/what-glue-should-i-use-for-permanent-lego-construction), otherwise as Ambo100 states, take a look at the storage questions.

Comment: You could invest in a nice shelving system to place completed ships for display - that seems like a better method than gluing or coating them.

Comment: I disagree with the duplication.  The dupe is talking about unassembled bricks, and this question is clearly talking about completed models.

Comment: @DaveDelong I think we can all agree that as it's written this question is a bit ambiguous; it could also have been marked as a duplicate of: [How do you store your built models for long term display?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/949/how-do-you-store-your-built-models-for-long-term-display)

Comment: @DaveDeLong If the question is rephrased to be less ambiguous and less like either of the questions in the "Linked" list, I'll be happy to reopen and clear down these comments :)